# Showing that an operator generates a contraction semigroup

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

Let $A$ be the infinitesimal generator of a contraction semigroup $(T(t))_{t\ge 0}$ on the Hilbert space $X$, and $D\in\mathcal{L}(X)$.

I want to show that the operator $A+D-2\|D\|I$ with domain $D(A)$ generates a contraction semigroup on $X$.

By the Lummer-Phillips Theorem, we have that if $A$ is a linear operator with domain $D(A)$ on a Hilbert space $X$, then $A$ is the infinitesimal generator of a contraction semigroup $(T(t))_{t\ge 0}$ if and only if $A$ is dissipative and $ran(I-A)=X$.

We have that a linear operator $A:D(A)\subset X\to X$ is dissipative if and only if

$$\|(\alpha I-A)x\|\ge\alpha\|x\|$$

for $x\in D(A)$, $\alpha>0$.

So for $\alpha>0$, we have

$\|(\alpha I-(A+D-2\|D\|I)x\|=\|(\alpha I-A-D+2\|D\|I)x\|$

Where do I go from here?

Comment: What is $D$? What properties does it have?

Comment: @T.A.E. $D\in\mathcal{L}(X)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're working on a complex Hilbert space, the range condition and the following condition are equivalent to dissipative:
$$
                 \Re(Ax,x) \le 0,\;\;\; x \in \mathcal{D}(A).
$$
This last condition persists if you add another bounded operator $C$ satisfying the same condition. In your case, because $D$ is bounded,
$$
                     |(Dx,x)| \le \|D\|\|x\|^{2},\\
                        \Re(Dx,x) \le \|D\|\|x\|^{2}, \\
                        \Re((D-\|D\|I)x,x) \le 0.
$$
Let
$$
                  B = A+(D-\|D\|I)
$$
Because $\Re(Bx,x) \le 0$, it follows that $B$ is dissipative iff $B-\alpha I$ is surjective for some real $\alpha > 0$ because $\mathcal{R}(B-\alpha I)$ is the same for all $\alpha > 0$. Notice that
\begin{align}
    B-\alpha I & = (A-\alpha I)+(D-\|D\|I) \\
         & = \{I+(D-\|D\|I)(A-\alpha I)^{-1}\}(A-\alpha I)
\end{align}
The operator in braces is invertible for large enough $\alpha$ because
$$
        \|(D-\|D\|I)(A-\alpha I)^{-1}\| \le 2\|D\|/\alpha < 1
$$
for large enough $\alpha > 0$. Hence, $B-\alpha I$ is surjective because the operator on the right is surjective for large enough $\alpha$. And that gives you what you want: $B$ is the generator of a contractive $C_{0}$ semigroup. The same is true of $B-\|D\|I$, which is the operator you wanted to know about.

Comment: $$
                        \Re(Dx,x) \le \|D\|\|x\|^{2}, \\
                        \Re((D-\|D\|I)x,x) \le 0.
$$

Could you explain this step please?

Comment: @user3482534 : The real part of the inner product is bounded by the absolute value of the inner product, which, by Cauchy-Schwarz, is bounded by the products of norms of vectors.

Comment: I was talking about how you derived $\Re((D-\|D\|I)x,x)\le 0$ from the inequality above?

Comment: @user3482534 : $\Re(Dx,x) \le \|D\|\|x\|^{2}=\|D\|\Re(x,x) = \Re ((\|D\| I)x,x)$

Comment: For 'Because $\Re(Bx,x) \le 0$, it follows that $B$ is dissipative iff $B-\alpha I$ is surjective for some real $\alpha > 0$'

Do you mean that it is a contraction semigroup (rather than 'dissipative' (since this would be the Lummer-Phillips theorem and $\Re(Bx,x) \le 0$ suggests that $B$ is dissipative by definition anyway)?

Comment: Further, shouldn't it be that $B-\alpha I=(A-\alpha I)+(D-\|D\|I)$?

And also, how did you get this inequality:

$\|(D-\|D\|I)(A-\alpha I)^{-1}\|\le 2\|D\|/\alpha<1$?

Comment: @user3482534 : $A : \mathcal{D}(B)\subseteq X\rightarrow X$ is a densely-defined linear generator of a contractive semigroup on a Hilbert space $X$ iff $\Re(Ax,x) \le 0$ for $x\in\mathcal{D}(A)$ and $A-\alpha I$ is surjective for some $\alpha > 0$ (and hence for all such $\alpha$.) You can have $\Re(Ax,x) \le 0$, but that's not enough. You are given $A$ is a generator. Then $B=A+(D-\|D\|I)$ satisfies $\Re(Bx,x) \le 0$; all that remains to show $B$ is a generator is to show that $B-\alpha I$ is surjective for some $\alpha > 0$ (and hence, for all $\alpha > 0$.)

Comment: @user3482534 : Concerning the inequality ... $\|D-\|D\|I\| \le 2\|D\|$. Because $A$ is a generator of a contractive $C^{0}$ semigroup, then $\|(A-\alpha I)^{-1}\| \le 1/\alpha$ for $\alpha > 0$. Putting those pieces together gives $\|(D-\|D\|I)(A-\alpha I)^{-1}\| \le 2\|D\|/\alpha$ for all $\alpha > 0$, which is strictly bounded by $1$ for large enough positive $\alpha$. And, you're right that I added an extra negative. I'll correct that now. The argument is unchanged.